# Parsing JSON with groovy LAX parser gives wrong keys

Tags: json, parsing, groovy

I have some config files in JSON format, and I need to parse them in a program written in groovy. Since the files should be human readable, I'd like to use the LAX syntax (and parser) so that I do not need to wrap every key and value in quotation marks and also can use comments.

But somehow, when I parse a JSON file, I get wrong keys in the resulting map.

Here is an example.

The JSON file (I saved it as a.json) is

```
{
    key1: aaa,
    key2: bbb
}
```

The program to parse it is

```
package test.json;

import groovy.json.JsonParserType;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

public class JsonParser {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX)
        def config = slurper.parse(new File('a.json'))
        println "key1: ${config.key1}"
        println "key2: ${config.key2}"
        for (e in config) {
            println "*** '${e.key}' (${e.key.class}) = '${e.value}' (${e.value.class})"
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute the program, I get the following output:

```
key1: aaa
key2: null
*** 'key1' (class java.lang.String) = 'aaa' (class java.lang.String)
*** '
    key2' (class java.lang.String) = 'bbb
' (class java.lang.String)
```

You see that the second key is not parsed as 'key2' but includes spaces and a line break.

How can I make the parser to remove the spaces from the keys and values so that I get `'key2'='bbb'` (as I'd expect for the file above)?

If I enclose each key and value in double quotation marks, everything is parsed as expected, i.e. I get `'key2'='bbb'`. But I thought with the LAX parser I'd not need them.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem you have shown in the question. I took the file content you have pasted and the code you added - Groovy 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0-alpha executed as expected. I would suggest checking the input file - maybe there is some character that breaks `key2` to the next line. Try the same sample but with JSON as a string variable passed to `slurper.parseText()`. And check the input file character encoding. LAX parser works as you described, it does not add any new line character. If you see it, it means it exists in the input file somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it (parsing the text from a string variable) and it worked. Then I switched back to the file, but placed both values on the same line -- and it worked. So I assumed it should somehow depend on newlines. I changed the newline to UNIX style (LF only) -- and it works! I don't understand why it doesn't work with Windows style newlines (CR, LF). For the reference: I use groovy 2.4.15, and I'm on a Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me now, the clue is to use the `normalize()` method:

```
def json = new File('a.json').text.normalize()
def config = slurper.parseText(json)
```